# Is the Math.random() method in java truly random?

Tags: java, android, math, random

I'm using the Math.random() method to assign 1 of 3 bitmaps to many object so they all look different when they appear on the screen by calling a random number then assigning a bitmap according to where that number lies between 0 and 1 for every object, but I keep seeing patterns like the same bitmap appearing in a row many times, is this just me looking for patterns where there are none? And is there a better way to randomise things like this?

Comment: `"...is this just me looking for patterns where there are none?"` -- quite possibly. `Math.random()` can never be "truly random", but it should be random *enough* to satisfy the needs of that (and most) programs.

Comment: How are you performing the assignment? Is there truly an equal probability for any of the three bitmaps?

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that is "more random" than the standard Java RNG, then you need to use a cryptographic RNG.  This will be slower and you will not be able to repeat the same random sequence by setting a seed since the RNG takes various internal system inputs as well as any seed you provide.  See `java.security.SecureRandom` for details.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "truly" random, but it is "random enough". There are few truly random sources, such as atmospheric noise. Perhaps the method you use to create bitmaps naturally creates similar patterns.

Answer (score 1):

JDK1.7 doc says :Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to use a seed so that a different sequence is generated each time. see (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers. In order to guarantee this property, particular algorithms are specified for the class Random

With a seed you can generate the same results and by using different seeds , you can guarantee that a different number sequence will be generated.